# Apex user data type isn't working

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, user-defined-types

How do I set user data type in report?

I have only in report "address type", but I need street, number, post code. Database is working, but I don't know how to set address type in report.

```
Create type Address_type
(

Street char(30),
Number integer,
Postcode integer

);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a function that will return your type, than in APEX you can use it as a table